# iterating through 2 rows of same list in c#

Tags: c#

1. I am trying to iterate through a (List<List>) using a "for loop", then find sum of selected column when added to corresponding colum of the next row inside a textbox. i.e columns of row 1 added to columns of row2, then create a new row with sum values.
   Row values in Textbox:

```
    03 06 16 18 58
    20 43 51 55 15
    08 24 43 28 39
```

4. After addition of row column values hereabove, I expect to have two rows with column values as follows: Values Required:

```
    23 49 67 73 73
    28 67 43 83 54
```

5. I attempted it in the following way, but it doesn't sum all the three rows. I really don't know where i am getting it wrong!

```
  for (int row1 = 0; row1 < textinsideTextbox.Count - 1; row1++)<br/>
  {
     for (int nextRow = row1 + 1; nextRow < textinsideTextbox.Count - 1; nextRow ++)
     { 
       for (int columnselector = 0; columnselector < availableColumns.Count; columnselector++) //number of columns
       { 
         int valuesRequired =  textinsideTextbox[row1][columnselector] + textinsideTextbox[nextRow][columnselector];              
       } 
     }
   }
```

Comment: 1) I suspect this problem only needs *two* loops. 2) Changing a row (List) *also* changes that row (the same List!) also on subsequent access; using a *different/new* output list will avoid this issue.

Comment: You can simplify your problem when you _transpose_ your `List<List<int>>` so that the rows become columns and vice versa. Then you can, for each inner list, add to each element its predecessor. But remember that you'll have to do it backwards starting from the back. Otherwise you will add an already incremented element to its successor.

Comment: In case it is allowed to use libraries, I'd recommend [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) which makes such list operations much easier. Have a look at the `Transpose()` and `Pairwise()` functions.

Comment: Why is the result second row third item `43` and not `94`?

Comment: Yes it should be 94, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Zip` twice: once to combine the pairs of lists, and once to combine the pairs of numbers:

```
var ans = src.Zip(src.Skip(1),(l1,l2) => l1.Zip(l2, (n1,n2) => n1+n2).ToList()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

The following seems to work as intended (with the values I tested).

[image: scr1]

[image: scr2]

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // read values
    List<List<int>> matrix = new List<List<int>>();
    using (var fs = new System.IO.StringReader(textBox1.Text))
    {
        while (fs.Peek()>=0)
        {
            var line = fs.ReadLine();
            var row = line.Split(' ').Select((item) => int.Parse(item)).ToList();
            matrix.Add(row);
        }
    }

    // process matrix
    List<List<int>> result = new List<List<int>>();
    for (int i = 1; i < matrix.Count; i++)
    {
        result.Add(matrix[i-1].Zip(matrix[i], (x, y) => x+y).ToList());
    }

    // write values
    using (var fs = new System.IO.StringWriter())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
        {
            fs.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", result[i].Select((item) => item.ToString("D2"))));
        }
        textBox1.Text = fs.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much @JohnAlexiou!!!. This is exactly what i needed.